# Deploying and running Java EE projects

Tags: jakarta-ee

I am new to Java EE and I had just followed an Oracle manual on how to build Java EE projects. Also, I was told to deploy and run it, the following steps had to be taken:

1. right click on the project and select the 'clean and Build'
2. right click on the project again and select 'Undeploy and deploy'to deploy the application on a Glassfish server.
3. Finally, right click on the project for the third time and select 'run' to open up the web browser

but in the second option, I only found the 'deploy' option and nothing like 'deploy and Undeploy' I am using the Netbeans 6.9.1 for building the application on a Glassfish server. I got the following error:

```
"Starting GlassFish Server 3
GlassFish Server 3 start failed.
/Users/henryjoseph/Downloads/ContactDemoApplication/nbproject/build-impl.xml:279:     
Deployment error:
GlassFish Server 3 start failed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 minutes 19 seconds)"
```

If there is any one who has experienced this error and knows how to correct it, kindly let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the Netbeans output. The hint is given in the second line from the bottom

> See the server log for details

In Netbeans there should be another tab in the output window named "Glassfish Server 3.xx". Click on this tab. It shows the server log file. If it is not there right click on the server node in the "Services" tab and choose "View Domain server log".

Comment: I did check the server log and I got no hint. I tried to refresh it but still failed..

Comment: Is your server starting correctly without deploying (right click on server node and "Start server")?

Comment: It is but says something like this :
"Shutting down v3 due to startup exception : Address already in use: 7676=com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ServiceInitializerHandler@35f6ef01"

Comment: Maybe another glassfish instance running on the same machine and your Netbeans' glassfish tries to use the already occupied ports?

Comment: well, i just killed all java processes with this linux command :

ps -ef | grep java | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
and yet nothing happened :(

Comment: Maybe the port is occupied by another process. Glassfish normally needs 8080 for http, 8081 for https and 4848 for the admin console. Can you check these ports with netstat?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9924/discussion-between-henry-joseph-and-matt-handy)